# selenium : choose a div tag and text via python

Tags: python, web-applications, selenium

I started learning selenium couple of hrs back. I have div tag like this

```
 <div id="first">
 <iframe src="/emulator/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div id="second">
 //some more html tags
  </div>
```

How to choose above div tag and send some text via selenium py code? (Tried google search for more than an hr -  still didn't find way)
Here's the python code snippet which leads up to the required div  tag page.

```
 class Wm2(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
      self.base_url = "http://localhost/"
      self.verificationErrors = [] 
      self.accept_next_alert = True

  def test_wm2(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("NAME")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("PWD123")
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
    #how to choose div tag  and send_some text ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case inside the `div` tag there is an `iframe`. In Web Driver if you want to do any actions inside the frame mean first yiu have to go inside the frame.

**Code to get in to the frame:**

```
 driver.switch_to_frame("Frame Name");
 //Do some actions on the frame
```

Once you finished your actions in the frame you have to leave the frame to perform any other action

**Code to leave the frame:**

```
driver.switch_to_default_content();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='second']//input").send_keys("your Text here");
```

Answer (score -4):

```
def test_wm2(self):
driver = self.driver
driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("NAME")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("PWD123")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```